# NSTimer Confusion

Tags: swift, nstimer

I'm trying to have a label subtract every second (a countdown of sorts) and when I make a variable "timer" and set it to NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "countdown", userInfo: nil, repeats: true) it won't work. The countdown function that I'm trying to call subtracts from the label but when I try to put the "countdown" in the selector it says to replace it with #selector(Hard.countdown). All the tutorials on YouTube are different so I do not know what to do. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post a sample of the code including the definition of `func countdown()`.

Comment: The `#selector` syntax is new to Swift 2.2 which was introduced less than a month ago. You can still use the old way, but it's deprecated. I recommend you learn Swift from the official Swift book provided by Apple instead of using YouTube videos, as it is always up to date.

Comment: Xcode 7.3 (Swift 2.2) changed the selector syntax.  You can use `Selector("countdown")` or what Xcode suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 2.2 added the new `#selector` syntax for safer selector. (We use pure string before). For NSTimer, you'll need to have a countdown method like the following:

```
func countdown(timer: NSTimer)
```

Don't forget the parameter, otherwise it won't work. And reference it as a selector like this: `#selector(Hard.countdown(_:))`